# Why ./helloworld and not helloworld directly to run my program from terminal?

Tags: macos, unix, command-line

As the question asked I thought "." means the current directory so why can't we directly type helloworld to run the program?

Comment: I removed the C++ tag because this applies to all executables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `'.'`, the current directory, is not in your environment's `$PATH`, which contains the list of paths where executables get searched. To see your `PATH` variable, type

```
echo $PATH
```

This is most likely for security reasons, to prevent execution of local executables named after system or other trusted installed ones. I have worked on systems where `'.'` was in the `PATH` and at the very least it lead to some confusing moments (the [`test`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?test) utility being a favourite candidate for accidental replacement.)

I would advise against appending `'.'` to `PATH` for those reasons.

Comment: To elaborate on this answer, not having `.` in the `$PATH` is a *good* thing. Think what would happen if there was a program named `ls` in the current directory, and you wanted to list file? Then the local `ls` program would be invoked and not `/bin/ls`.